# add an account in the accountmanager

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a user account in my app with accountManager, by entering the user data and password to make the registration hangs me or returns me to the initial window of the app.
The app opens well the registration section from mobile accounts.

```
        registration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
            //username = settings.getString("", "");

                Account[]accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(getResources().getString(R.string.account_type));
                if(accounts.length <= 0){
                    requestLogin();
                }else{
                    accountFound = false;
                    for(Account account : accounts){
                        if(account.name.equals(username) && account.type.equals(password)){
                            accountFound = true;
                            authToken = getAuthToken(account);
                            loginWithUser(username, password);
                        }
                    }
                    if(!accountFound){
                        requestLogin();
                }
            }
        }

}

private void requestLogin(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private String getAuthToken(Account account) {
    return "";
}

private void loginWithUser(String userName, String passWord) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Login with the user name \"" + userName + "\" and the authToken \"" + passWord);
}
```

In my class Service and AbstractAccountAuthenticator:

```
public class AccountAuthenticatorService extends Service {

private static final String LOG_TAG = AccountAuthenticatorService.class.getSimpleName();
private static AccountAuthenticatorImpl sAccountAuthenticator = null;

public AccountAuthenticatorService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    IBinder ret = null;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(android.accounts.AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT)) {
        ret = getAuthenticator().getIBinder();
    }
    return ret;
}

public AbstractAccountAuthenticator getAuthenticator() {
    if (AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator == null) {
        AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator = new AccountAuthenticatorImpl(this);
    }
    return AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator;
}

private static class AccountAuthenticatorImpl extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
    private Context mContext;

    public AccountAuthenticatorImpl(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        Bundle reply = new Bundle();
        Intent add = new Intent(mContext, AccountManagerSimpleActivity.class);
        add.setAction("");
        add.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
        reply.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, add);
        return reply;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

And in the class Preference:

```
public class Preference {

private static final String PREFS_NAME = "auth";
private static final String KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name";
private static final String KEY_AUTH_TOKEN = "auth_token";

private SharedPreferences preferences;

public Preference(Context context) {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public String getAccountName() {
    return preferences.getString(KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
}

public String getAuthToken() {
    return preferences.getString(KEY_AUTH_TOKEN, null);
}

public void setUsername(String accountName) {
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
    editor.commit();
}

public void setAuthToken(String authToken) {
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_AUTH_TOKEN, authToken);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}